# How to put serials in a data frame by group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There is a data frame with a model and an item as a column below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'model':['A','A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B','B'],
       'item':['aa','ab','ab','ab','ac','ad','ad','ba','ba','ba','bb','bb','bb','bc']})
```

[image]

I want to add a serial column to this data frame, but there are some rules

1. The serial number is reset when the model(A, B) is changed and starts from zero.
2. Serial cannot exceed 3.

   0, 1, 2 values only

   After two(2), it starts at zero(0)
3. In the case of the same item, serial is be the same

***what I want is***

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want [`pd.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) on `item` within each `model` group (`groupby`). The reset part is just a modulo away:

```
df['serial'] = df.groupby(['model'])['item'].transform(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0]) % 3
```

Output:

```
   model item  serial
0      A   aa       0
1      A   ab       1
2      A   ab       1
3      A   ab       1
4      A   ac       2
5      A   ad       0
6      A   ad       0
7      B   ba       0
8      B   ba       0
9      B   ba       0
10     B   bb       1
11     B   bb       1
12     B   bb       1
13     B   bc       2
```

Comment: Thank you for the easy, concise solution~

Answer (score 4):

Compare each item with the previous and apply a cumulative sum. The rest is a math operation to adjust to your expected output (count starts from 0 and not exceed 3)

```
to_serial = lambda x: x.ne(x.shift()).cumsum().sub(1).mod(3)
df['serial'] = df.groupby('model')['item'].transform(to_serial)
print(df)

# Output
   model item  serial
0      A   aa       0
1      A   ab       1
2      A   ab       1
3      A   ab       1
4      A   ac       2
5      A   ad       0
6      A   ad       0
7      B   ba       0
8      B   ba       0
9      B   ba       0
10     B   bb       1
11     B   bb       1
12     B   bb       1
13     B   bc       2
```

Answer (score 1):

If need count by consecutive values in `item` use:

```
df['serial'] = (df['item'].ne(df['item'].shift()).cumsum()
                          .groupby(df['model'])
                          .rank(method='dense').astype(int).sub(1).mod(3))
```

Or:

```
df['serial'] = (df['item'].ne(df['item'].shift()).cumsum()
                          .groupby(df['model'])
                          .transform(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0]).mod(3))
```

---

```
print (df)
   model item  serial
0      A   aa       0
1      A   ab       1
2      A   ab       1
3      A   ab       1
4      A   ac       2
5      A   ad       0
6      A   ad       0
7      B   ba       0
8      B   ba       0
9      B   ba       0
10     B   bb       1
11     B   bb       1
12     B   bb       1
13     B   bc       2
```